# Encrypt and save in external storage the String response of Json as a textfile

Tags: android

I am new in Text file Encryption in Android. And tried so many example of text encryption but i am so confused how to apply.
I have 5 string records from json response and i want to save them in a text file(in External Storage) and in "Encrypted format" . I've tried code of cipher_text_encoding but really confused with lots of classes in it.
Please suggest me either good tutorial for text encryption or give me hint how to encode.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Encryption and Decryption using AES Secret Key Algorithm**

Generate AES Secret Key:

```
public static byte[] generateAesSecretKey(){
    String SALT2 = "strong_salt_value";
    String username = "user_name";
    String password = "strong_password";
    byte[] key = (SALT2 + username + password).getBytes();
    SecretKey secretKeySpec = null;

    try {
        MessageDigest sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
        key = sha.digest(key);
        key = Arrays.copyOf(key, 16);
        secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return secretKeySpec.getEncoded();
}
```

Encryption:

```
public static byte[] encodeFile(byte[] secretKey, byte[] fileData) {
    SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey, "AES");
    byte[] encrypted = null;
    try {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
        encrypted = cipher.doFinal(fileData);

        // Now write your logic to save encrypted data to sdcard here
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return encrypted;
}
```

Decryption:

```
public static byte[] decodeFile(byte[] key, byte[] fileData) {
    SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
    byte[] decrypted = null;
    try {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
        decrypted = cipher.doFinal(fileData);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch(Exception e){
        // for all other exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return decrypted;
}
```

Hope above methods are useful for you!

Comment: you are welcome! you can accept my answer if it helps you!

Answer (score 0):

AS with every beginner it is normal to get confused, instead of do it yourself everything learn to leverage on **code reuse** or written shared libraries. This will leverage on **code abstraction** as you are only interested in say Encryption and Decryption of JSON/Sting.

For a Full Document:

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html

For a reusable (Java/Android) library:

- https://github.com/alkathirikhalid/security

**Simple Usage:**

```
String plainText = "Your String";
String encryptionKey = "Your Encryption Key";
String IV = "Your Initial Vector";

// To Encrypt
String cipherText = AES.encrypt(plainText, encryptionKey, IV);

// To Decrypt returned value same as plainText
String originalText = AES.decrypt(cipherText, encryptionKey, IV);
```

Cheers.

Comment: thanks @Al-Kathiri Khalid and yess its really confusing I'll try ur links.

Comment: Glad I could help, if you find my answer helpful and relevant please do accept it so as to be helpful to others too.

Comment: definitely, Thanks again.